# How to count occurrence in previous rows based on two columns value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to count the number of occurrence in previous rows based on two conditional values using Google Sheet.

Let say this is my table :

| Row A | Row B | Row C | Row D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Smith |  |
| 2 | Marty | Butler |  |
| 3 | John | Herbert |  |
| 4 | John | Smith |  |
| 5 | Philip | Rand |  |
| 6 | John | Smith |  |
| 7 | Marty | Butler |  |

Is there a formula that exist that can count those occurrences. The idea is that when I log a new name, if Row B and C already exist it increase the value in Row D by 1 so I would know that it is the nth entry under that name. In my example, Row D would looks like this:

| Row A | Row B | Row C | Row D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Smith | 1 |
| 2 | Marty | Butler | 1 |
| 3 | John | Herbert | 1 |
| 4 | John | Smith | 2 |
| 5 | Philip | Rand | 1 |
| 6 | John | Smith | 3 |
| 7 | Marty | Butler | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete everything in Column D (including the header) and place the following in D1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Header";IF(B2:B="",,COUNTIFS(B2:B&C2:C,B2:B&C2:C,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A)))})`

The "Header" text can be edited as you like.

The `COUNTIFS` reads, in plain English, "Count how many times this first and last name combination has occurred within only the rows up to the current row."